# Usage of the -I flag of bash's complete command

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I want `bash` to autocomplete `cod<TAB>` to `codium` (discarding other commands that might also start with `cod`)

Looking at the [manual of the `complete` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#index-complete), I found the `-I` flag which seems to be what I need.

I ended up with the following solution:

```
complete -I -F _command_completions -o bashdefault

function _command_completions() {
  # cod<tab> completes to codium
  [[ $2 == cod* ]] && COMPREPLY="codium"
}
```

which works, but I was wondering: Is there a more succinct way of achieving the same result?

For example, something like:

```
complete -I -W 'codium' cod
```

this causes the words: empty string, `c`, `co`, `cod`, `codi`, and `codiu` to complete to `codium` which is not what I want.

Comment: for `complete -I -W 'codium' cod`, the `cod` would actually be ignored. your initial solution is simple enough. just go with it.